# Properties of upper triangular matrix with complex entries

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be an upper triangular matrix with complex entries. Pick out the true statement(s):

(a) If $A \neq 0$ and $a_{ii}=0$ for all $1\le i\le n$ then $A^n=0$.

(b) If $A \neq I$ and $a_{ii}=1$ for all $1\le i\le n$ then $A$ is not diagonalizable.

(c) If $A \neq 0$ then $A$ is invertible.

Comment: (a) (b) $\,\,\!\!$

Comment: Answer is correct. But I need explanations against each statement

Comment: Well, come up with them, then.

Comment: a), b) have a look at the characteristic polynomial, it is easy to compute for upper triangular matrices. a) What do you know about eigenvalues of nilpotent matrices? b) How would the diagonalization look like?

Comment: for case (a) trace is 0 so sum of eigen values is 0.Now is for a upper triangular matrix with diagonal entries d1, d2,....dn is the chreterstic poly is (x-d1)(x-d2).....(x-dn)? if so then for case (a) it is $x^n$ so by caly hamilton them $A^n$=$0$ is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(a): True

**Hint:**

- approach 1: use the Cayley hamilton theorem.  What do we know about the eigenvalues, and what does this tell us about the characteristic equation?
- approach 2: suppose $A$ is strictly upper-triangular (i.e. is upper-triangular but with zeros on the diagonal).  You should find that the entries that are two above the diagonal must also be zero.  Show that this pattern continues, and that any such $n \times n$ matrix must satisfy $A^n = 0$.

(b): True

- approach 1: if $A$ is diagonalizable, what is the dimension of $\ker(A - I)$?  Can you show that $A - I = 0$?
- approach 2: show that all eigenvalues of $A$ are equal to 1.  It follows that if $A$ is diagonalizable, we can write $A = SIS^{-1} = SS^{-1} = I$.

(c): False; try to find a counterexample.  Consider the effect of changing the diagonal entries.

Comment: I have understood case(a) but I have no idea about the hint given in case(b)..please explain it further

Comment: for case (b) ch poly is $(x-1)^n$?

Comment: For case b, we find the characteristic polynomial is indeed $(x-1)^n$ for any upper triangular matrix with $1$s on the diagonal.  What we have to check is whether certain such matrices are diagonalizable.  So, here's a question: given a matrix, how do we check if it's diagonalizable? What does it mean for a matrix to be diagonalizable?

Comment: @nothingobvious Yes, the only eigenvalue is $1$ but to be diagonalizable you should find a basis of the space consisting of eigenvectors. The equation $(A-I)x=0$ is non-trivial. So, the eigenvalues span something smaller than the whole space.

Comment: still not clear to me how to relate ker($A-I$)?

Comment: On the contrary: if the solutions to $(A-I)x$ span anything smaller than the entire space, then $A$ is not diagonalizable. Here's another way to think about it: suppose that $A$ is diagonalizable, with $1$ as its only eigenvalue.  Then, we must be able to write $A = SIS^{-1} = SS^{-1} = I$

Comment: The idea before was to note that eigenvectors of an eigenvalue $\lambda$ are by definition linearly independent solutions to $(A - \lambda I)x = 0$. If $A$ is diagonalizable with $1$ as its only eigenvector, then $(A - I)x = 0$ must have $n$ linearly independent solutions. It therefore follows that $A - I$ is *identically zero*.

Comment: for case (c) if$A$ is 2*2 matrix all entries 0 except (1,2) th entry taking i, then det($A$)=0. Is it ok to counter (c)?

Comment: Yes, $\pmatrix{0 & 1\\ 0 & 0}$ is a good counterexample.  Another counterexample is $\pmatrix{1 & 0\\0&0}$. The key is that an upper diagonal matrix is invertible if and only if all of its diagonal entries are non-zero.

Comment: Thank you for giving the solution